# Highcharts - hide legend if there is no value

Tags: highcharts

I am trying to hide the legend for values that are zero. How can this be done?

```
[enter link description here][1]
```

I have tried using

```
function(chart){
        var flag = false;

        $.each(chart.series,function(i,serie){

            $.each(serie.data,function(j,data){

                if(data.y === 0){
                    flag=true;

                }
            });

            if(flag)
               serie.legendGroup.destroy();

        });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can iterate by each serie / points, check if is 0 value and remove legend group in SVG.

http://jsfiddle.net/hz2PN/

```
var flag = false;

 $.each(chart.series,function(i,serie){

            $.each(serie.data,function(j,data){

                if(data.y === 0){
                    flag=true;

                }
            });

            if(flag)
               serie.legendGroup.destroy();

        });
```